# Return value of EF function doesn't return values properly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ValidateUser] 
    (@useremail varchar(100),
     @password varchar(100))    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    DECLARE @DECRYPTEDPASSWORD VARCHAR(100)

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY PASSWORDKEY DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ASAPDBCertificate with password = 'asap012ASAP'

    SELECT @DECRYPTEDPASSWORD = CONVERT (VARCHAR , DECRYPTBYKEY([PASSWORD]))  
    FROM dbo.gb_admin_userinfo 
    WHERE UPPER(EMAIL) = UPPER(@useremail )

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY PASSWORDKEY

    IF (@DECRYPTEDPASSWORD = @password)
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.gb_admin_userinfo 
        WHERE UPPER(EMAIL) = UPPER(@useremail)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1
    END
END
```

Sample invocation:

```
EXEC  [SP_ValidateUser] 'anvesh@adaequare.com','1223123'
```

If password is correct it returns 1 & is null if wrong password.

Entity Framework:

```
using (var db = new ASAPEntities())
{
    string cmdText = string.Format("exec SP_ValidateUser @useremail, @password");
    SqlParameter parEmail = new SqlParameter("@useremail", email);
    SqlParameter parPassword = new SqlParameter("@password", password);

    var r = db.Database.SqlQuery<SP_ValidateUser_Result>(cmdText, parEmail, parPassword).ToList();

    var res = db.SP_ValidateUser(email, password).ToList();
}

using (var db = new ASAPEntities())
{
    ObjectParameter parIsValidUser = new ObjectParameter("isvaliduser", DbType.Boolean);
    db.sp_IsValidUser(email, password, parIsValidUser);
    var result = parIsValidUser.Value is DBNull ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(parIsValidUser.Value);
    return result;
}
```

The end result always shows true.

Please add comment if you need any further information.

The problem is the stored procedure is executing correctly in SQL Server, but EF doesn't return proper value.

I also updated the edmx file, checked function imports etc.

**UPDATING as per comment:**

What is ASAPEntities? Is it a DbContext created with the designer? 
 - Yes, it is DBContext & it is created by designer.

Why do you include the 2nd using in your question? Is the problem linked to that? If not, you should remove it from the question to isolate the problem. 
- I tried in two ways hence the 2nd.

What is SP_ValidateUser_Result?
- It is a complex type returned through the SP.

Can you try with bool instead? You don't seem do anything with either r or res; that's suspicious to me. Also, why would you need both r and res; is that only tests when you were trying stuff? 
- These are the tests which I tried.

You say it doesn't return values properly, but where have you checked the value? – I executed in my SSMS to see if my SP is proper or not.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Your stored procedure logic says that if password is correct it will return data from a table otherwise return 1 but in description you are saying reverse. Can you review it and see if you are not mssing anything obvious. What happens when you call the stored procedure via sql management studio?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : you are right,, that code was a type. But, you understood what I tried to explain right:)

Comment: What is `ASAPEntities`? Is it a DbContext created with the designer? Why do you include the 2nd using in your question? Is the problem linked to that? If not, you should remove it from the question to isolate the problem. What is `SP_ValidateUser_Result`? Can you try with `bool` instead? You don't seem do anything with either `r` or `res`; that's suspicious to me. Also, why would you need both `r` and `res`; is that only tests when you were trying stuff? You say it doesn't return values properly, but where have you checked the value?